# PHP PDO query to mssql server sometimes gets no response from server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to run a very simple test query using PDO and the dblib driver to get data from a remote MSSQL server. The test query is:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE part = 'ABC123'
```

When I load the page in Chrome I get a message, almost instantly, saying: "No Data Received" with an error code of ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Loading it in FireFox has the same result but with the message: "The Connection Was Reset".

I've tried using mssql_query instead of PDO and it works perfectly, so I thought it must be a problem with my PDO connection code. The code I use to connect is:

```
new PDO("dblib:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;dbname=xxxx","user","pass",
                array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

The thing that has got me stumped is that the PDO code connects to the database fine and when I run the query:

```
SELECT ID,partNumber,description FROM product WHERE part ='ABC123'
```

It works as expected, and I don't get any of the response/connection errors as before.

I've spent hours searching Google but can't find a reason why I'm getting these errors.

Does anyone have a solution or any idea as to what's causing this problem? I would like to use PDO instead of `mssql_query` as I want to make use of PDO's features, but at the moment, `mssql_query` seems to be my only option.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb you should avoid `SELECT *` in applications.

Comment: You've tagged this as "MySQL", I take it you are just using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Neil, its just a test script that uses SELECT * to make sure there were no problems getting all the data I will need. The finished project won't use any SELECT *.

Comment: Yes its a Microsoft SQL Server I'm connecting to, sorry. I've removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: Can we see what you wrote for the pdo piece?

Comment: The full code is: `$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE KeyCode = 'ABC123'"); ` and then `$reply = $query->execute(); `